# Sharing MacOS network links to Windows User

Tags: macos, network, windows, sharing, smb

At work I'm one of the few employees working on a MacOs. I often get Windows shared network links from colleagues and convert them locally with a script...more or less successful.

For e.g. (Windows Style) :

```
\\networkshare\folder\subfolder\file.pdf
```

to (MacOs Style):

```
smb://networkshare/folder//file.pdf
```

Also vice versa would be interesting! I've seen an automator script, but It's not working properly...

Comment: "locally with a script"… can you show us what you have so far & why it isn't satisfactory - otherwise it's just a request for someone to do it all for you.

Comment: …and what makes this in any way different to your previous question? For now I've closed it against the same duplicate. If you edit to show what you've done & what more you need, it can be flagged for re-opening.